# How can I pull a string from an array and then check the first letter of it?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

```
  puts "Please Enter First Initial..."
  initial = gets
  first_letter( name, age, initial)  

  def first_letter( x, y, z)
       index = 0
       while index < x.length
        --->if z == (x[index])
        puts "#{x[index]}   #{y[index]}"
        end
        index += 1
      end
    end
```

So essentially what I'm trying to do is use the above code to pull a word from an array and then check the first letter of that string for a match. Essentially it asks the user for a letter and then it checks that letter against the first letter of each string in the array. The marked line is supposed to check the letter against the first letter of the string. If it is equal to the letter, the program is to put the name and age of that entry.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the array into the method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, but the following code selects all the strings from the array where the first letter is an `a`. Maybe this gets you on the right track:

```
a #=> ["a", "b", "c", "aa", "bb", "cc", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] 
a.select { |x| x[0] == ?a } #=> ["a", "aa", "aaa"]
# or
a.select { |x| x.start_with? 'a' } #=> ["a", "aa", "aaa"]
```

Comment: Thanks. that helped me figure it out!

Answer (score 3):

```
a = %w{ axxx bxxx aaaa cccc azz }
# => ["axxx", "bxxx", "aaaa", "cccc", "azz"] 

a.grep(/^a/)
# => ["axxx", "aaaa", "azz"]
```

Consider [Enumerable#grep](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method with a little bit of [regex](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html).

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say. This is an assignment that I can't use hashes in. It has to be two aligned arrays.